# TypeError: 'ResourceProtector' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib, flask-oauthlib

According to the Authlib documentation, there is a built-in approach to use introspection endpoint to validate the given token when resource server has no access to token database:

```
import requests
from authlib.oauth2.rfc7662 import IntrospectTokenValidator
from your_project import secrets

class MyIntrospectTokenValidator(IntrospectTokenValidator):
    def introspect_token(self, token_string):
        url = 'https://example.com/oauth/introspect'
        data = {'token': token_string, 'token_type_hint': 'access_token'}
        auth = (secrets.internal_client_id, secrets.internal_client_secret)
        resp = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=auth)
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return resp.json()
```

We can then register this token validator in to resource protector:

```
require_oauth = ResourceProtector()
require_oauth.register_token_validator(MyIntrospectTokenValidator())
```

When I use @require_oauth for my api routes, I have the following error:

```
TypeError: 'ResourceProtector' object is not callable
```

Can someone help please?

Source: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc7662.html#use-introspection-in-resource-server

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The problem has been found. Wrong source import

Correct one:

```py
authlib.integrations.flask_oauth2
```